# Macro effect in the code

Tags: c

suppose I have a macro, like

```
#define max(a,b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

then I use it in the "normal code"

```
int foo()
{
...
c = max(a,b);
...
}
```

Is there a way to see the code after precompiling?
Does exist a way to see the effect of macro substituion (maybe done by compiler, I use gcc)?

I'd like to get something like this:

```
int foo()
{
...
c = ((a>b) ? a : b);
...
}
```

Is there something like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to see the preprocessed source code. Usually your C compiler has a switch to output the preprocessed output.

For gcc, it's `gcc -E [C-filename]`.

For msvc, it's `cl /EP` or `cl /P`. See [MSVC /P (Preprocess to a File)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: a warning that this will generate a very large file with every pre-processor substitutions done.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`cpp`, the GCC C preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1.1/cpp/).

`gcc` is only a collection of tools: `cpp`, `cc` and `ld` for examples.

Comment: Or equivalently, use `gcc -E`.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: true. the documentation of gcc is long, but all switches are documented.

Answer (score 1):

For GCC you can also use [-save-temps](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) option. This will generate 3 intermediate files:

- *.i -> C preprocessed source
- *.s -> assembly output (by default in AT&T syntax, but can be switched to Intel also).
- *.o -> object file.

I prefer this option, because it gives more control over compilation process.